# Matching a ] (closing square bracket) with PATINDEX using the "[ ]" wildcard

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, pattern-matching, string-searching

I am writing a custom JSON parser in T-SQL<sup>†</sup>.

For the purpose of my parser, I am using the `PATINDEX` function that calculates the position of a token from a list of tokens. The tokens in my case are all single characters and they include these:

```
{ } [ ] : ,
```

Usually, when I need to find the (first) position of any of several given characters, I use the [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) function like this:

```
PATINDEX('%[abc]%', SourceString)
```

The function will then give me the first position of `a` or `b` or `c` – whichever happens to be found first – in `SourceString`.

Now the problem in my case seems to be connected with the `]` character. As soon as I specify it in the character list, e.g. like this:

```
PATINDEX('%[[]{}:,]%', SourceString)
```

my intended pattern apparently becomes broken, because the function never finds a match. It looks like I need a way to escape the first `]` so that `PATINDEX` treats it as one of the lookup characters rather than a special symbol.

I have found this question asking about a similar problem:

- [Need help with LIKE operator and square brackets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187364/need-help-with-like-operator-and-square-brackets)

However, in that case the `]` simply does not need to be specified in brackets, because it is just one character and it can be specified without brackets around them. The alternative solution, which does use escaping, works only for `LIKE` and not for `PATINDEX`, because it uses an `ESCAPE` subclause, supported by the former and not by the latter.

So, my question is, **is there any way to look for a `]` with `PATINDEX` using the `[ ]` wildcard?** Or is there a way to emulate that functionality using other Transact-SQL tools?

#### Additional Information

Here is an example of a query where I need to use `PATINDEX` with the `[…]` pattern as above. **The pattern here works (albeit *somewhat*) because it does not include the `]` character.** I need it to work with `]` as well:

```
WITH
  data AS (SELECT CAST('{"f1":["v1","v2"],"f2":"v3"}' AS varchar(max)) AS ResponseJSON),
  parser AS
  (
    SELECT
      Level         = 1,
      OpenClose     = 1,
      P             = p.P,
      S             = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, 1, NULLIF(p.P, 0) - 1),
      C             = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, NULLIF(p.P, 0), 1),
      ResponseJSON  = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, NULLIF(p.P, 0) + 1, 999999)
    FROM
      data AS d
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[[{]%', d.ResponseJSON)) AS p (P)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      Level         = ISNULL(d.OpenClose - 1, 0) + d.Level + ISNULL(oc.OpenClose, 0),
      OpenClose     = oc.OpenClose,
      P             = d.P + p.P,
      S             = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, 1, NULLIF(p.P, 0) - 1),
      C             = c.C,
      ResponseJSON  = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, NULLIF(p.P, 0) + 1, 999999)
    FROM
      parser AS d
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[[{}:,]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, d.ResponseJSON)) AS p (P)
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, NULLIF(p.P, 0), 1)) AS c (C)
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN c.C IN ('[', '{') THEN 1 WHEN c.C IN (']', '}') THEN 0 END) AS oc (OpenClose)
    WHERE 1=1
      AND p.P <> 0
  )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  parser
OPTION
  (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

The output I get is:

```
Level  OpenClose  P   S      C   ResponseJSON
-----  ---------  --  -----  --  ---------------------------
1      1          1          {   "f1":["v1","v2"],"f2":"v3"}
1      null       6   "f1"   :   ["v1","v2"],"f2":"v3"}
2      1          7          [   "v1","v2"],"f2":"v3"}
2      null       12  "v1"   ,   "v2"],"f2":"v3"}
2      null       18  "v2"]  ,   "f2":"v3"}
2      null       23  "f2"   :   "v3"}
2      0          28  "v3"   }
```

You can see that the `]` is included as part of `S` in one of the rows. The `Level` column indicates the level of nesting, meaning bracket and braces nesting. As you can see, once the level becomes 2, it never returns to 1. It would have if I could make `PATINDEX` recognise `]` as a token.

The expected output for the above example is:

```
Level  OpenClose  P   S     C   ResponseJSON
-----  ---------  --  ----  --  ---------------------------
1      1          1         {   "f1":["v1","v2"],"f2":"v3"}
1      NULL       6   "f1"  :   ["v1","v2"],"f2":"v3"}
2      1          7         [   "v1","v2"],"f2":"v3"}
2      NULL       12  "v1"  ,   "v2"],"f2":"v3"}
2      0          17  "v2"  ]   ,"f2":"v3"}
1      NULL       18        ,   "f2":"v3"}
1      NULL       23  "f2"  :   "v3"}
1      0          28  "v3"  }
```

You can play with this query [at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=99d6e1ebe536c6e5cccf399c6bd0ffd0).

---

<sub><sup>†</sup> We are using SQL Server 2014 and are unlikely to soon upgrade to a version that supports JSON parsing natively. I could write an application to do the job but the results of the parsing need to be processed further, which implies more work in the application than just the parsing – the kind of work that would be much easier, and probably more efficiently, done with a T-SQL script, if only I could apply it directly to the results.</sub>

<sub>It's very unlikely that I can use SQLCLR as a solution for this problem.  However, I don't mind if someone decides to post a SQLCLR solution, since that could be useful for others.</sub>

Comment: What about json that looks like `["foo]bar”]`?

Comment: @SalmanA: Such scenarios can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My own solution, which is more of a workaround, consisted in specifying a character range that included the `]` and using that range along with the other characters in the `[ ]` wildcard. I used a range based on the ASCII table. According to that table, the `]` character is located in the following neighbourhood:

```
Hex  Dec  Char
---  ---  ----
…
5A   90   Z
5B   91   [
5C   92   \
5D   93   ]
5E   94   ^
5F   95   _
…
```

My range, therefore, took the form of `[-^`, i.e. it included four characters: `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`. I also specified that the pattern use a Binary collation, to match the ASCII range exactly. The resulting `PATINDEX` expression ended up looking like this:

```
PATINDEX('%[[-^{}:,]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, MyJSONString)
```

The obvious problem with this approach is that the range at the beginning of the pattern includes two unwanted characters, `\` and `^`. The solution worked for me simply because the extra characters could never occur in the specific JSON strings I needed to parse. Naturally, this cannot be true in general, so I am still interested in other methods, hopefully more universal than mine.

Comment: ugly and great! with this I can exclude "^" in PATINDEX like this [^\-^]. new emoji?

Answer (score 4):

I have a probably terrible take on this from back when I had to do a lot of string splitting.

If you have a known set of characters, make a table of them.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.characters ( character CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED );

INSERT dbo.characters ( character )
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT '[' UNION ALL
        SELECT ']' UNION ALL
        SELECT '{' UNION ALL
        SELECT '}' UNION ALL
        SELECT ',' 
) AS x (v)
```

Then use that magical `CROSS APPLY` along with `CHARINDEX`:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 p.Id, p.Body, ca.*
FROM dbo.Posts AS p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 CHARINDEX(c.character, p.Body) AS first_things_first
    FROM dbo.characters AS c
    ORDER BY CHARINDEX(c.character, p.Body) ASC
) AS ca
WHERE ca.first_things_first > 0
```

If I'm missing something obvious about what you need to do, lemme know.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen approaches in the past to replace the offending character before searching, and putting it back in afterwards.

In this case we could do something like:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @replacementcharacter CHAR(1) = CHAR(174);

SET @test = 'Test[]@String'

SELECT PATINDEX('%[[' + @replacementcharacter + '@]%', REPLACE(@test,']',@Replacementcharacter))
```

This code correctly returns 5. I'm using the ¬ character as that's unlikely to appear - if there are no ASCII characters you won't be using, this solution won't work.

Oddly enough though, the direct answer to your question would be no - I can't get PATINDEX to search for ']' either, but if you replace it you don't need to.

Same example but without the variable usage:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @test = 'Test[]@String'

SELECT PATINDEX('%[[' + CHAR(174) + '@]%', REPLACE(@test,']',CHAR(174)))
```

Using the above solution in your code yields your required results:

```
WITH
  data AS (SELECT CAST('{"f1":["v1","v2"],"f2":"v3"}' AS varchar(max)) AS ResponseJSON),
  parser AS
  (
    SELECT
      Level         = 1,
      OpenClose     = 1,
      P             = p.P,
      S             = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, 1, NULLIF(p.P, 0) - 1),
      C             = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, NULLIF(p.P, 0), 1),
      ResponseJSON  = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, NULLIF(p.P, 0) + 1, 999999)
    FROM
      data AS d
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[[{'+ CHAR(174) + ']%', REPLACE(d.ResponseJSON,']',CHAR(174)))) AS p (P)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      Level         = ISNULL(d.OpenClose - 1, 0) + d.Level + ISNULL(oc.OpenClose, 0),
      OpenClose     = oc.OpenClose,
      P             = d.P + p.P,
      S             = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, 1, NULLIF(p.P, 0) - 1),
      C             = c.C,
      ResponseJSON  = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, NULLIF(p.P, 0) + 1, 999999)
    FROM
      parser AS d
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[[{}:,'+ CHAR(174) + ']%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, REPLACE(d.ResponseJSON,']',CHAR(174)))) AS p (P)
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, NULLIF(p.P, 0), 1)) AS c (C)
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN c.C IN ('[', '{') THEN 1 WHEN c.C IN (']', '}') THEN 0 END) AS oc (OpenClose)
    WHERE 1=1
      AND p.P <> 0
  )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  parser
OPTION
  (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `]` is only special in `[...]`, you can use `PATINDEX` twice, moving `]` outside of the `[...]`. Evaluate both `PATINDEX('%[[{}:,]%', SourceString)` and `PATINDEX('%]%', SourceString)`. If one result is zero, take the other one. Otherwise, take the lesser of the two values.

In your example:

```
WITH
  data AS (SELECT CAST('{"f1":["v1","v2"],"f2":"v3"}' AS varchar(max)) AS ResponseJSON),
  parser AS
  (
    SELECT
      Level         = 1,
      OpenClose     = 1,
      P             = p.P,
      S             = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, 1, NULLIF(p.P, 0) - 1),
      C             = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, NULLIF(p.P, 0), 1),
      ResponseJSON  = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, NULLIF(p.P, 0) + 1, 999999)
    FROM
      data AS d
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[[{]%', d.ResponseJSON)) AS p (P)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      Level         = ISNULL(d.OpenClose - 1, 0) + d.Level + ISNULL(oc.OpenClose, 0),
      OpenClose     = oc.OpenClose,
      P             = d.P + ISNULL(p.P, 0),
      S             = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, 1, p.P - 1),
      C             = c.C,
      ResponseJSON  = SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, p.P + 1, 999999)
    FROM
      parser AS d
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[[{}:,]%', d.ResponseJSON), 0), NULLIF(PATINDEX('%]%', d.ResponseJSON), 0))) AS p_ (a, b)
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CASE WHEN p_.a < p_.b OR p_.b IS NULL THEN p_.a ELSE p_.b END)) AS p (P)
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(d.ResponseJSON, p.P, 1)) AS c (C)
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN c.C IN ('[', '{') THEN 1 WHEN c.C IN (']', '}') THEN 0 END) AS oc (OpenClose)
    WHERE 1=1
      AND p.P <> 0
  )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  parser
OPTION
  (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=66fba2218d8d7d310d5a682be143f6eb

Answer (score -4):

For a left '[':

```
PATINDEX('%[[]%',expression)
```

For a right ']':

```
PATINDEX('%]%',expression)
```

Comment: This specifies how to search for either an opening square bracket, or a closing one; the OP is looking for one of several characters (noted by enclosing the characters in question in square brackets), including a closing square bracket.